# Cкрипт для Windows автоматически меняющий Название.jpg на i++.jpg (прошлое название + 1)

Tags: python, windows, bash

Возможно ли написать скрипт для Windows и на каком языке / И/ИЛИ есть иные способы достижения цели :
Суть скрипта: При перекидывании определенного файлового формата (png, jpg, jpeg) в определенную папку имя файла меняется на `число + 1` от прошлой итерации `(i+1)`
Для чего?
Есть определенная База Данных в Excel с путями картинок с уже прописанными названиями.
В этот путь нужно закинуть определенные картинки, соответствуя содержанию и названию

```html
Пр.
FOLDER/1.jpg FOLDER/2.jpg FOLDER/3.jpg
Мои действия - перекидывать в папку FOLDER картинку, переименовывать ее из Some_Name.jpg в 1.jpg следующую картинку в 2.jpg итд
Почему нужен скрипт?
База Данных состоит из 5 тысяч путей => нужно переименовывать все 5 тысяч картинок
```

Answer (score 0):

total_commander ctrlA ctrlM + mask [c1+1:2] помогают

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1272419/edit) PS Где скрипт? ))

Comment: совсем не похоже на «скрипт для windows». разве это ответ на ваш вопрос?